# How can I make a radio button enabled but the text look disabled

Tags: android

I want some radio buttons that have disabled looking text, but the radio buttons look normal.

The user can click the radio buttons and will show some teasers about future versions, but I also want to show clearly what features are not available yet.

Here is a picture:

[image]

And my code so far, **I'm actually hoping for a better solution**, but if that is not the case the below code has the following problems:

- Because the test radios are not under the radio group layout they will not uncheck the other siblings,
- Because the tests are actually 2 radios (one is a button and not text, the other a text with not button) clicking the text does not check the button! which is actually important!
- It appears that writing more than a line will wrap but it goes outside the linear layout by a few pixels.

  ```
  <RadioGroup
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <RadioButton
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Normal, unchecked" />

      <RadioButton
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Normal, unchecked" />

      <RadioButton
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:checked="true"
          android:text="Normal, checked" />

      <RadioButton
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:text="Disabled, unchecked" />

      <RadioButton
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:checked="true"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:text="Disabled, checked, also big line saijdhnasoidasokdmokasmdokasmdkmasdplmaslk;dmsal;kdmas;lmdl;asmdl;mas;ldmasl;dmaslkmdksamdasmdlka" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <RadioButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

          <RadioButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:button="@null"
              android:enabled="false"
              android:text="Test, unchecked, also big line saijdhnasoidasokdmokasmdokasmdkmasdplmaslk;dmsal;kdmas;lmdl;asmdl;mas;ldmasl;dmaslkmdksamdasmdlka" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <RadioButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:checked="true" />

          <RadioButton
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:button="@null"
              android:enabled="false"
              android:text="Test, checked" />
      </LinearLayout>

  </RadioGroup>
  ```

Comment: set the text color same as for disabled

Comment: change the color(?)

Comment: @VladMatvienko good idea, but is the same color used on all android devices?

Comment: no, but you can define you theme, which will be applied on all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the color using `getCurrentTextColor()` and then use `setTextColor(color)` on the radio button

```
    RadioButton checkbox=(RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.first);
    checkbox.setEnabled(false);
    int color=checkbox.getCurrentTextColor();
    checkbox.setEnabled(true);
    checkbox.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use textcolor attribute

```
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:textColor="#AAA"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, was searching for more info. Your answer is good, but once you change the background color the text is out of sync with the disabled radioboxes.